# How to simplify this expression with radicals? $3\sqrt2 - \sqrt{32} + \sqrt{\frac{80}{16}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, fractions

I don't understand how I could calculate this:
$3\sqrt2 - \sqrt{32} + \sqrt{\dfrac{80}{16}}$

My answer is $-\sqrt2 + \sqrt5$, but the real answer should be $\dfrac{9-4\sqrt2}{4}$.

Comment: Maybe it was $\sqrt{\frac{81}{16}}$?

Comment: Your answer is perfectly correct for what you posted !

Comment: Did you try to check the question again? Answer seems right .@DanielFischer it is very likely $\sqrt{\frac{81}{16}}$

Comment: Oh... I am so blind.
Yes, it's 81/16. Haha... :|
Thank you guys for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commenters pointed out, $80$ should be $81$. The radicals simplify as follows:
$$
3\sqrt2 - \sqrt{32} + \sqrt{\dfrac{81}{16}} = 
3\sqrt{2}- \sqrt{16} \sqrt{2} +\frac94 = (3-4)\sqrt{2}+\frac94 = \frac94-\sqrt{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant $81$: $$ \begin {align*} 3\sqrt2 - \sqrt{32} + \sqrt{\dfrac{81}{16}} &= 
3\sqrt{2}- \sqrt{16} \sqrt{2} +\frac94 \\&= (3-4)\sqrt{2}+\frac94 \\&= \frac94-\sqrt{2}. \end {align*} $$